# Load Byte array content to Browser in Angular 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I am working on an Angular 4 project with ASP.Net Web API and trying to load a byte array content in browser in form of PDF. I am returning a HttpResponseMessage that has byte array from my ASP.Net Web API but I am not getting the response at client. Here is my code --

```
Server side (C#)    
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
var stream = new MemoryStream(offerLetterPdfByte);
//offerLetterPdfByte is the byte array of a dynamically created pdf document
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());

Angular Code in Component
public PreviewOfferLetter() {
    const editorContentHtml = this.frmReviewOfferLetter.controls["EditorNote"].value;
    this._humanResourceService.PreviewCandidateOfferLetter(editorContentHtml).subscribe(
      data => {
        const file = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
        const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileUrl);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {

      });
  }

//Method In Service
public PreviewCandidateOfferLetter(offerLetterHtml: any): Observable<any>{
    return this._httpHelperService.ExecutePostRequest(ApiUrlConfig.HumanResource.PreviewCandidateOfferLetter, offerLetterHtml);
  }
```

The server side method is of type HttpPost and is executing very well. I am able to see the byte array while debugging the server code, but the response is not coming to the data part in my component, it always hits the error part and the error object is as follows --

```
 error = Object {StatusCode: undefined, Message: undefined}

//Service Code
public ExecutePostRequest(endpoint: any, params?: any, customErrorCallback?: any): Observable<any> {
      this._requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
          method: RequestMethod.Post,
          url: this.baseUrl + endpoint,
          headers: this.headers,
          body: JSON.stringify(params),
          withCredentials: true
      });
      this._loggerService.Log("info", "Execute Request : " + this.baseUrl + endpoint, null, "HttpHelperService", "executeRequest", params);
      return this._http.request(new Request(this._requestOptions)).map(this.ExtractData).catch(customErrorCallback !== undefined ? customErrorCallback : this.HandleError);
    }
```

Please suggest I am doing something wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you share your angular service code

Comment: @Chellappan - I edited the question. Please see the service code there.

Comment: on console what error are you getting?

Comment: @Chellappan - {Status: undefined, Message: undefined}